# How to describe this URL in apache rewrite engine?

Tags: regex, apache, apache2

How would you write the regex to include this kind of url:

```
page/(various-option)
```

where `various-option` can be something like:

```
page/gratis
page/gratis-images
page/weekly-images
page/yearly-images
page/yearly
page/images
```

(And all other combination of the params) At the moment I am using something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/((gratis)?\-?(weekly|yearly)?\-?(images)?)$ /page.php?options=$1 [L]
```

(Note: I omitted other params)

In the rewrite engine I wrote there is a problem, a malformed url like this for example would be parsed too:

```
page/-yearly-
```

Or even worse:

```
page/--images
```

Thanks for any suggestion

ADD1:

`weekly-gratis-weekly` is wrong and should be refused.

There are exctly 5 params (but i don't think the regex would change if the params were 3)

And all of the params can be combinated (except the one like weeky|yearly of course)

ADD2 (@tim):

the order of params is important.

This is not allowed `page/images-yearly-gratis` (but the regex i wrote already checks the oreder) The correct url in this case is

```
page/gratis-yearly-images
```

Comment: Do you need to refuse options that occur more than once? Is `page/weekly-gratis-weekly` possible and has to be caught? How many different parameters are there, and are all of them allowed in any combination?

Comment: Please name all the parameters and the order in which they may appear.

Comment: @tim: the params i wrote up there are perfect for an example  **(gratis)-(weekly|yearly)-(images)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
^page/((?:gratis(?=$|-.))?-?(?:(?:weekly|yearly)(?=$|-.))?-?(?:images)?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # start
page/        # page/
(            # start capturing
 (?:gratis   # try matching "gratis"
  (?=$|-.)   # if it's the last item or followed by - and more characters
 )?          # optional match
 -?          # match a - if possible
 (?:         # the same with weekly|yearly
  (?:weekly|yearly)
  (?=$|-.)
 )?
 -?
 (?:images)? # finally, try matching images.
)            # end of capture
$            # end of string
```

Comment: It's a non-capturing group. I need to group it so I can apply the `?` to the entire group, but I don't need to reference it later (as in `$1` which I do need for the surrounding group).

Comment: That's what I meant. Since I don't need any more than that, I don't need any more capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page/(((gratis)(-|$))?((weekly|yearly)(-|$))?(images)?)$ /page.php?options=$1 [L]
```

Also worth mentioning that the above rule only works in a *.htaccess* file. If you want to put it into an apache configuration file the pattern should start with `^/page`.

Comment: Is **page/-images** a legal URL? Is **page/images** a legal URL? From your examples it seems none of them are OK, and this pattern refuses both. Please clarify this in your examples.

Comment: Have you tried it in Apache? I'm pretty sure **page/-images** will NOT go thru this pattern.

Comment: Hey man, just try it out. And I would emphasize that the pattern is not: ***yearly)?(-images** - there is no question mark after the yearly clausure.

Comment: @yes123: And you voted this down because this is a wrong answer?

Comment: I wrote a clear comment why I voted the topic down. It still stands and I would also add "voting down working answer" to the list. - I don't know what makes you go personal on people trying to solve your problem, and I honestly don't care. I've got nothing to add to this conversation any more.